# Good idea to include test logs in software repository?

Tags: version-control

I have written a software in python with unit tests and system tests together with an other developer. The software is version controlled with git. Before we merge branches, we ensure that the branches pass the tests, so conflicts after merge is only related to merge.

Is it a good idea to version control the test logs as well in software repository?

edit:

Specifically, the test logs are the output of the test executions; list of all the tests and if they passed or failed.

The tests are all automated, so no user interaction is needed to execute the tests.

Comment: In your workflow, what are "test logs"? Do they record observed output? Do they specify *expected* output? Are they steps to follow when doing manual tests?

Comment: @KilianFoth, clearified this in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not a good idea. Source Control is named that way because it contains source, not the compiled result, or test output in your example. Test logs are temporary files that are used only to debug tests, and thus should not be present in the source control.

Comment: Further, if a comitted version of the code fails a test that was committed with it, you should be able to retrieve and build that version, run the test again and get the exact same failure.